# Estatísticas de autonomia de bateria de celular em python

Tags: python

Eu tenho esses dados do uso da bateria do meu celular que capturei usando o Tasker:

```
97 - 1467514184514
tela desligada - 1467514366535
tela ligada - 1467514369196
96 - 1467514414616
95 - 1467514674523
94 - 1467514924621
93 - 1467515154585
92 - 1467515364555
91 - 1467515644567
90 - 1467515904577
89 - 1467516164576
88 - 1467516444576
87 - 1467516724599
86 - 1467516974598
85 - 1467517234639
84 - 1467517524627
83 - 1467517774639
tela desligada - 1467517831625
tela ligada - 1467517844633
82 - 1467518044654
81 - 1467518304726
80 - 1467518564731
79 - 1467518854649
tela desligada - 1467519062759
tela ligada - 1467519065287
78 - 1467519114701
tela desligada - 1467519222448
tela ligada - 1467519224361
tela desligada - 1467519268223
tela ligada - 1467519270241
tela desligada - 1467519313549
tela ligada - 1467519315661
77 - 1467519394673
tela ligada - 1467519525076
77 - 1467519534643
76 - 1467519625736
75 - 1467519874688
74 - 1467520114710
tela desligada - 1467520268384
tela ligada - 1467520277494
73 - 1467520364777
tela desligada - 1467520374973
tela ligada - 1467520375570
tela desligada - 1467520510265
tela ligada - 1467520512333
tela desligada - 1467520535432
tela ligada - 1467520536223
tela desligada - 1467520626069
tela ligada - 1467520628278
72 - 1467520644742
tela ligada - 1467520726202
tela desligada - 1467520728528
72 - 1467520742118
tela ligada - 1467520742157
carregando bateria - 1467520742203
tela desligada - 1467520743675
73 - 1467520841112
tela ligada - 1467520848617
tela desligada - 1467520864967
74 - 1467520931093
75 - 1467521011773
76 - 1467521091225
77 - 1467521171491
78 - 1467521241273
79 - 1467521311313
80 - 1467521381433
81 - 1467521451291
82 - 1467521521127
83 - 1467521591250
84 - 1467521661254
85 - 1467521731324
86 - 1467521801328
87 - 1467521871262
88 - 1467521941243
89 - 1467522021200
90 - 1467522101530
91 - 1467522191145
92 - 1467522291331
93 - 1467522401305
94 - 1467522521292
95 - 1467522661469
96 - 1467522821464
97 - 1467523021208
98 - 1467523261325
99 - 1467523561392
100 - 1467524071444
tela ligada - 1467543507927
tela desligada - 1467543522847
tela ligada - 1467543553598
tela desligada - 1467543555464
desarregando bateria - 1467543570366
tela ligada - 1467543570466
tela desligada - 1467543572805
tela ligada - 1467543573367
tela ligada - 1467543762197
100 - 1467543769538
tela desligada - 1467543799334
tela ligada - 1467543801542
tela desligada - 1467543824793
tela ligada - 1467543834876
99 - 1467543933770
tela ligada - 1467543996645
99 - 1467544003623
tela ligada - 1467544153861
98 - 1467544163912
97 - 1467544323634
tela desligada - 1467544325142
tela ligada - 1467544329638
tela desligada - 1467544386685
tela ligada - 1467544483093
tela desligada - 1467544571038
96 - 1467544609004
tela ligada - 1467544609039
tela ligada - 1467544745366
96 - 1467544748377
95 - 1467544798445
94 - 1467545068409
93 - 1467545308429
92 - 1467545558429
tela ligada - 1467545595320
tela desligada - 1467545597590
92 - 1467545598382
tela ligada - 1467545696894
tela desligada - 1467545757555
tela ligada - 1467545933920
91 - 1467546013522
tela desligada - 1467546113335
tela ligada - 1467546140287
90 - 1467546318244
tela ligada - 1467546377997
90 - 1467546378382
tela desligada - 1467546409534
tela ligada - 1467546451043
89 - 1467546630530
tela desligada - 1467546663460
tela ligada - 1467546814986
tela desligada - 1467546825432
88 - 1467547523083
tela ligada - 1467550033900
tela desligada - 1467550061241
tela ligada - 1467550063275
tela ligada - 1467550132143
88 - 1467550133363
87 - 1467550233622
86 - 1467550503471
85 - 1467550843458
tela desligada - 1467550908878
tela ligada - 1467550927895
84 - 1467551207421
83 - 1467551557383
tela desligada - 1467551790452
tela ligada - 1467552405020
tela desligada - 1467552425594
tela ligada - 1467552865867
82 - 1467552875404
tela desligada - 1467552885894
tela desligada - 1467552888918
82 - 1467553007104
tela ligada - 1467554234966
81 - 1467554244423
tela ligada - 1467554326023
81 - 1467554344363
tela desligada - 1467554355202
80 - 1467554451089
tela ligada - 1467554463059
tela desligada - 1467554507173
tela desligada - 1467554510531
80 - 1467554512114
tela ligada - 1467554535934
79 - 1467554635456
tela ligada - 1467554689882
79 - 1467554695461
tela desligada - 1467554766183
tela ligada - 1467554768110
tela desligada - 1467554778616
tela ligada - 1467554803911
78 - 1467554853440
77 - 1467555083503
76 - 1467555383387
75 - 1467555623525
74 - 1467555873422
73 - 1467556113534
tela ligada - 1467556152852
73 - 1467556153400
tela ligada - 1467556184928
73 - 1467556193424
72 - 1467556323438
71 - 1467556583452
70 - 1467556823513
69 - 1467557103509
tela desligada - 1467557191455
tela ligada - 1467557490051
tela desligada - 1467557494232
tela ligada - 1467557858175
tela ligada - 1467557879460
tela desligada - 1467557879482
tela ligada - 1467557908318
68 - 1467557914380
tela desligada - 1467557925409
tela ligada - 1467558492101
tela desligada - 1467558510096
tela ligada - 1467558887050
tela desligada - 1467558921283
tela ligada - 1467559261338
67 - 1467559270523
66 - 1467559440485
```

O meu objetivo é descobrir quanto tempo leva para mudar o status da bateria com a tela ligada, desligada, e também se está carregando o celular ou não. Em python eu fiz esse script para pegar os dados do arquivo lol.txt:

```
import glob, time, pprint

a = glob.glob('*.txt')[:1]

def postar_bonito(kk):
    l = []
    x = kk.splitlines()
    for k in x:
        m, o = k.split(' - ')
        o = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(o)/1000))
        if m[0].isdigit(): m += '%'
        l.append('%s - %s' % (o, m))
    return '\n'.join(l)

def estava_ligado(x):
    m = f.index('tela desligada')
    mm = f.index('tela ligada')
    return mm > m

def remover_repetidos(s):
    last = 'lolcopter'
    k = []
    for i, e in enumerate(s):
        lolcopter = e.split(' - ')[0]
        if lolcopter != last:
            k.append(lolcopter)
        last = lolcopter
    return k

def estava_carregando(j):
    lol = remover_repetidos([m for m in j.splitlines() if m[0].isdigit()])
    return int(lol[0]) < int(lol[1])

def prettytime(x):
    return time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(x) / 1000))

def prettytime2(x):
    o, k = divmod(x, 60)
    return '%02d:%02d' % (o, k)

def process(x, y, z):
    return [z, prettytime(x), prettytime(y), prettytime2((int(y) - int(x)) / 1000)]

for i in a:
    f = file(i, 'r').read()
    carregando_tela_ligada = []
    carregando_tela_desligada = []
    descarregando_tela_ligada = []
    descarregando_tela_desligada = []
    carregando = estava_carregando(f)
    tela = estava_ligado(f)
    last = None
    last_percent = None
    for h in f.splitlines():
        g, r = h.split(' - ')

        if g[0].isdigit():
            if g != last_percent:
                if last == None:
                    last = r
                if carregando:
                    if tela:
                        carregando_tela_ligada.append(process(last, r, last_percent))
                    else:
                        carregando_tela_desligada.append(process(last, r, last_percent))
                else:
                    if tela:
                        descarregando_tela_ligada.append(process(last, r, last_percent))
                    else:
                        descarregando_tela_desligada.append(process(last, r, last_percent))
                last = r
                last_percent = g

        if g == "tela desligada":
            tela = False
        if g == "tela ligada":
            tela = True
        if g == "descarregando bateria":
            carregando = False
        if g == "carregando bateria":
            carregando = True

    print "carregando_tela_ligada ="
    pprint.pprint(carregando_tela_ligada)
    print "carregando_tela_desligada ="
    pprint.pprint(carregando_tela_desligada)
    print "descarregando_tela_ligada ="
    pprint.pprint(descarregando_tela_ligada)
    print "descarregando_tela_desligada ="
    pprint.pprint(descarregando_tela_desligada)
```

O output é esse:

```
carregando_tela_ligada =
[['100', '03/07/2016 - 02:34:31', '03/07/2016 - 08:05:33', '331:02'],
 ['99', '03/07/2016 - 08:05:33', '03/07/2016 - 08:09:23', '03:50'],
 ['98', '03/07/2016 - 08:09:23', '03/07/2016 - 08:12:03', '02:39'],
 ['96', '03/07/2016 - 08:16:49', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:58', '03:09'],
 ['95', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:58', '03/07/2016 - 08:24:28', '04:29'],
 ['94', '03/07/2016 - 08:24:28', '03/07/2016 - 08:28:28', '04:00'],
 ['93', '03/07/2016 - 08:28:28', '03/07/2016 - 08:32:38', '04:10'],
 ['92', '03/07/2016 - 08:32:38', '03/07/2016 - 08:40:13', '07:35'],
 ['91', '03/07/2016 - 08:40:13', '03/07/2016 - 08:45:18', '05:04'],
 ['90', '03/07/2016 - 08:45:18', '03/07/2016 - 08:50:30', '05:12'],
 ['88', '03/07/2016 - 09:05:23', '03/07/2016 - 09:50:33', '45:10'],
 ['87', '03/07/2016 - 09:50:33', '03/07/2016 - 09:55:03', '04:29'],
 ['86', '03/07/2016 - 09:55:03', '03/07/2016 - 10:00:43', '05:39'],
 ['85', '03/07/2016 - 10:00:43', '03/07/2016 - 10:06:47', '06:03'],
 ['84', '03/07/2016 - 10:06:47', '03/07/2016 - 10:12:37', '05:49'],
 ['83', '03/07/2016 - 10:12:37', '03/07/2016 - 10:34:35', '21:58'],
 ['82', '03/07/2016 - 10:34:35', '03/07/2016 - 10:57:24', '22:49'],
 ['80', '03/07/2016 - 11:00:51', '03/07/2016 - 11:03:55', '03:04'],
 ['79', '03/07/2016 - 11:03:55', '03/07/2016 - 11:07:33', '03:37'],
 ['78', '03/07/2016 - 11:07:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:11:23', '03:50'],
 ['77', '03/07/2016 - 11:11:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:16:23', '04:59'],
 ['76', '03/07/2016 - 11:16:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:20:23', '04:00'],
 ['75', '03/07/2016 - 11:20:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:24:33', '04:09'],
 ['74', '03/07/2016 - 11:24:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:28:33', '04:00'],
 ['73', '03/07/2016 - 11:28:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:32:03', '03:29'],
 ['72', '03/07/2016 - 11:32:03', '03/07/2016 - 11:36:23', '04:20'],
 ['71', '03/07/2016 - 11:36:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:40:23', '04:00'],
 ['70', '03/07/2016 - 11:40:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:45:03', '04:39'],
 ['69', '03/07/2016 - 11:45:03', '03/07/2016 - 11:58:34', '13:30'],
 ['68', '03/07/2016 - 11:58:34', '03/07/2016 - 12:21:10', '22:36'],
 ['67', '03/07/2016 - 12:21:10', '03/07/2016 - 12:24:00', '02:49']]
carregando_tela_desligada =
[['72', '03/07/2016 - 01:37:24', '03/07/2016 - 01:40:41', '03:16'],
 ['73', '03/07/2016 - 01:40:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:42:11', '01:29'],
 ['74', '03/07/2016 - 01:42:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:43:31', '01:20'],
 ['75', '03/07/2016 - 01:43:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:44:51', '01:19'],
 ['76', '03/07/2016 - 01:44:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:46:11', '01:20'],
 ['77', '03/07/2016 - 01:46:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:47:21', '01:09'],
 ['78', '03/07/2016 - 01:47:21', '03/07/2016 - 01:48:31', '01:10'],
 ['79', '03/07/2016 - 01:48:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:49:41', '01:10'],
 ['80', '03/07/2016 - 01:49:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:50:51', '01:09'],
 ['81', '03/07/2016 - 01:50:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:52:01', '01:09'],
 ['82', '03/07/2016 - 01:52:01', '03/07/2016 - 01:53:11', '01:10'],
 ['83', '03/07/2016 - 01:53:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:54:21', '01:10'],
 ['84', '03/07/2016 - 01:54:21', '03/07/2016 - 01:55:31', '01:10'],
 ['85', '03/07/2016 - 01:55:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:56:41', '01:10'],
 ['86', '03/07/2016 - 01:56:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:57:51', '01:09'],
 ['87', '03/07/2016 - 01:57:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:59:01', '01:09'],
 ['88', '03/07/2016 - 01:59:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:00:21', '01:19'],
 ['89', '03/07/2016 - 02:00:21', '03/07/2016 - 02:01:41', '01:20'],
 ['90', '03/07/2016 - 02:01:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:03:11', '01:29'],
 ['91', '03/07/2016 - 02:03:11', '03/07/2016 - 02:04:51', '01:40'],
 ['92', '03/07/2016 - 02:04:51', '03/07/2016 - 02:06:41', '01:49'],
 ['93', '03/07/2016 - 02:06:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:08:41', '01:59'],
 ['94', '03/07/2016 - 02:08:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:11:01', '02:20'],
 ['95', '03/07/2016 - 02:11:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:13:41', '02:39'],
 ['96', '03/07/2016 - 02:13:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:17:01', '03:19'],
 ['97', '03/07/2016 - 02:17:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:21:01', '04:00'],
 ['98', '03/07/2016 - 02:21:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:26:01', '05:00'],
 ['99', '03/07/2016 - 02:26:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:34:31', '08:30'],
 ['97', '03/07/2016 - 08:12:03', '03/07/2016 - 08:16:49', '04:45'],
 ['89', '03/07/2016 - 08:50:30', '03/07/2016 - 09:05:23', '14:52'],
 ['81', '03/07/2016 - 10:57:24', '03/07/2016 - 11:00:51', '03:26']]
descarregando_tela_ligada =
[[None, '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '00:00'],
 ['97', '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '02/07/2016 - 23:53:34', '03:50'],
 ['96', '02/07/2016 - 23:53:34', '02/07/2016 - 23:57:54', '04:19'],
 ['95', '02/07/2016 - 23:57:54', '03/07/2016 - 00:02:04', '04:10'],
 ['94', '03/07/2016 - 00:02:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:05:54', '03:49'],
 ['93', '03/07/2016 - 00:05:54', '03/07/2016 - 00:09:24', '03:29'],
 ['92', '03/07/2016 - 00:09:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:14:04', '04:40'],
 ['91', '03/07/2016 - 00:14:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:18:24', '04:20'],
 ['90', '03/07/2016 - 00:18:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:22:44', '04:19'],
 ['89', '03/07/2016 - 00:22:44', '03/07/2016 - 00:27:24', '04:40'],
 ['88', '03/07/2016 - 00:27:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:32:04', '04:40'],
 ['87', '03/07/2016 - 00:32:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:36:14', '04:09'],
 ['86', '03/07/2016 - 00:36:14', '03/07/2016 - 00:40:34', '04:20'],
 ['85', '03/07/2016 - 00:40:34', '03/07/2016 - 00:45:24', '04:49'],
 ['84', '03/07/2016 - 00:45:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:49:34', '04:10'],
 ['83', '03/07/2016 - 00:49:34', '03/07/2016 - 00:54:04', '04:30'],
 ['82', '03/07/2016 - 00:54:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:58:24', '04:20'],
 ['81', '03/07/2016 - 00:58:24', '03/07/2016 - 01:02:44', '04:20'],
 ['80', '03/07/2016 - 01:02:44', '03/07/2016 - 01:07:34', '04:49'],
 ['79', '03/07/2016 - 01:07:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:11:54', '04:20'],
 ['78', '03/07/2016 - 01:11:54', '03/07/2016 - 01:16:34', '04:39'],
 ['77', '03/07/2016 - 01:16:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:20:25', '03:51'],
 ['76', '03/07/2016 - 01:20:25', '03/07/2016 - 01:24:34', '04:08'],
 ['75', '03/07/2016 - 01:24:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:28:34', '04:00'],
 ['74', '03/07/2016 - 01:28:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:32:44', '04:10'],
 ['73', '03/07/2016 - 01:32:44', '03/07/2016 - 01:37:24', '04:39']]
descarregando_tela_desligada =
[]
```

Porém os dados estão incorretos. No carregando com a tela ligada a energia está decrescendo e no carregando com a tela desligada está ok mas daí surge um 89 e um 81 do além!

Onde está o erro de lógica no meu script? Alguém sugere um jeito melhor de fazer o que eu quero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei o erro. No tasker eu estava escrevendo **desarregando** ao invés de **descarregando**.

Levei um bom tempo para conseguir achar o erro. Aí vai o diff com um debug que fiz, caso alguém esteja interessado no desenrolar.

https://www.diffchecker.com/qbhwmxpl

Aí segue o output que gerei para debugar:

```
1 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 97 - 1467514184514
2 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 96 - 1467514414616
3 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 95 - 1467514674523
4 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 94 - 1467514924621
5 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 93 - 1467515154585
6 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 92 - 1467515364555
7 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 91 - 1467515644567
8 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 90 - 1467515904577
9 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 89 - 1467516164576
10 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 88 - 1467516444576
11 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 87 - 1467516724599
12 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 86 - 1467516974598
13 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 85 - 1467517234639
14 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 84 - 1467517524627
15 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 83 - 1467517774639
16 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 82 - 1467518044654
17 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 81 - 1467518304726
18 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 80 - 1467518564731
19 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 79 - 1467518854649
20 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 78 - 1467519114701
21 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 77 - 1467519394673
22 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 77 - 1467519534643
23 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 76 - 1467519625736
24 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 75 - 1467519874688
25 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 74 - 1467520114710
26 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 73 - 1467520364777
27 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 72 - 1467520644742
28 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 72 - 1467520742118
29 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 73 - 1467520841112
30 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 74 - 1467520931093
31 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 75 - 1467521011773
32 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 76 - 1467521091225
33 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 77 - 1467521171491
34 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 78 - 1467521241273
35 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 79 - 1467521311313
36 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 80 - 1467521381433
37 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 81 - 1467521451291
38 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 82 - 1467521521127
39 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 83 - 1467521591250
40 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 84 - 1467521661254
41 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 85 - 1467521731324
42 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 86 - 1467521801328
43 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 87 - 1467521871262
44 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 88 - 1467521941243
45 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 89 - 1467522021200
46 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 90 - 1467522101530
47 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 91 - 1467522191145
48 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 92 - 1467522291331
49 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 93 - 1467522401305
50 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 94 - 1467522521292
51 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 95 - 1467522661469
52 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 96 - 1467522821464
53 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 97 - 1467523021208
54 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 98 - 1467523261325
55 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 99 - 1467523561392
56 - Carregando o celular com a tela desligada, 100 - 1467524071444
57 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 100 - 1467543769538
58 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 99 - 1467543933770
59 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 99 - 1467544003623
60 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 98 - 1467544163912
61 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 97 - 1467544323634
62 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 96 - 1467544609004
63 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 96 - 1467544748377
64 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 95 - 1467544798445
65 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 94 - 1467545068409
66 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 93 - 1467545308429
67 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 92 - 1467545558429
68 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 92 - 1467545598382
69 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 91 - 1467546013522
70 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 90 - 1467546318244
71 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 90 - 1467546378382
72 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 89 - 1467546630530
73 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 88 - 1467547523083
74 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 88 - 1467550133363
75 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 87 - 1467550233622
76 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 86 - 1467550503471
77 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 85 - 1467550843458
78 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 84 - 1467551207421
79 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 83 - 1467551557383
80 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 82 - 1467552875404
81 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 82 - 1467553007104
82 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 81 - 1467554244423
83 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 81 - 1467554344363
84 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 80 - 1467554451089
85 - Descarregando o celular com a tela desligada, 80 - 1467554512114
86 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 79 - 1467554635456
87 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 79 - 1467554695461
88 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 78 - 1467554853440
89 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 77 - 1467555083503
90 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 76 - 1467555383387
91 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 75 - 1467555623525
92 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 74 - 1467555873422
93 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 73 - 1467556113534
94 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 73 - 1467556153400
95 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 73 - 1467556193424
96 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 72 - 1467556323438
97 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 71 - 1467556583452
98 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 70 - 1467556823513
99 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 69 - 1467557103509
100 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 68 - 1467557914380
101 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 67 - 1467559270523
102 - Descarregando o celular com a tela ligada, 66 - 1467559440485
===========================================================
carregando_tela_ligada =
[]
carregando_tela_desligada =
[[29, '73', '03/07/2016 - 01:39:02', '03/07/2016 - 01:40:41', '01:38'],
 [30, '74', '03/07/2016 - 01:40:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:42:11', '01:29'],
 [31, '75', '03/07/2016 - 01:42:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:43:31', '01:20'],
 [32, '76', '03/07/2016 - 01:43:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:44:51', '01:19'],
 [33, '77', '03/07/2016 - 01:44:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:46:11', '01:20'],
 [34, '78', '03/07/2016 - 01:46:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:47:21', '01:09'],
 [35, '79', '03/07/2016 - 01:47:21', '03/07/2016 - 01:48:31', '01:10'],
 [36, '80', '03/07/2016 - 01:48:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:49:41', '01:10'],
 [37, '81', '03/07/2016 - 01:49:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:50:51', '01:09'],
 [38, '82', '03/07/2016 - 01:50:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:52:01', '01:09'],
 [39, '83', '03/07/2016 - 01:52:01', '03/07/2016 - 01:53:11', '01:10'],
 [40, '84', '03/07/2016 - 01:53:11', '03/07/2016 - 01:54:21', '01:10'],
 [41, '85', '03/07/2016 - 01:54:21', '03/07/2016 - 01:55:31', '01:10'],
 [42, '86', '03/07/2016 - 01:55:31', '03/07/2016 - 01:56:41', '01:10'],
 [43, '87', '03/07/2016 - 01:56:41', '03/07/2016 - 01:57:51', '01:09'],
 [44, '88', '03/07/2016 - 01:57:51', '03/07/2016 - 01:59:01', '01:09'],
 [45, '89', '03/07/2016 - 01:59:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:00:21', '01:19'],
 [46, '90', '03/07/2016 - 02:00:21', '03/07/2016 - 02:01:41', '01:20'],
 [47, '91', '03/07/2016 - 02:01:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:03:11', '01:29'],
 [48, '92', '03/07/2016 - 02:03:11', '03/07/2016 - 02:04:51', '01:40'],
 [49, '93', '03/07/2016 - 02:04:51', '03/07/2016 - 02:06:41', '01:49'],
 [50, '94', '03/07/2016 - 02:06:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:08:41', '01:59'],
 [51, '95', '03/07/2016 - 02:08:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:11:01', '02:20'],
 [52, '96', '03/07/2016 - 02:11:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:13:41', '02:39'],
 [53, '97', '03/07/2016 - 02:13:41', '03/07/2016 - 02:17:01', '03:19'],
 [54, '98', '03/07/2016 - 02:17:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:21:01', '04:00'],
 [55, '99', '03/07/2016 - 02:21:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:26:01', '05:00'],
 [56, '100', '03/07/2016 - 02:26:01', '03/07/2016 - 02:34:31', '08:30']]
descarregando_tela_ligada =
[[1, '97', '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '00:00'],
 [2, '96', '02/07/2016 - 23:49:44', '02/07/2016 - 23:53:34', '03:50'],
 [3, '95', '02/07/2016 - 23:53:34', '02/07/2016 - 23:57:54', '04:19'],
 [4, '94', '02/07/2016 - 23:57:54', '03/07/2016 - 00:02:04', '04:10'],
 [5, '93', '03/07/2016 - 00:02:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:05:54', '03:49'],
 [6, '92', '03/07/2016 - 00:05:54', '03/07/2016 - 00:09:24', '03:29'],
 [7, '91', '03/07/2016 - 00:09:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:14:04', '04:40'],
 [8, '90', '03/07/2016 - 00:14:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:18:24', '04:20'],
 [9, '89', '03/07/2016 - 00:18:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:22:44', '04:19'],
 [10, '88', '03/07/2016 - 00:22:44', '03/07/2016 - 00:27:24', '04:40'],
 [11, '87', '03/07/2016 - 00:27:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:32:04', '04:40'],
 [12, '86', '03/07/2016 - 00:32:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:36:14', '04:09'],
 [13, '85', '03/07/2016 - 00:36:14', '03/07/2016 - 00:40:34', '04:20'],
 [14, '84', '03/07/2016 - 00:40:34', '03/07/2016 - 00:45:24', '04:49'],
 [15, '83', '03/07/2016 - 00:45:24', '03/07/2016 - 00:49:34', '04:10'],
 [16, '82', '03/07/2016 - 00:49:34', '03/07/2016 - 00:54:04', '04:30'],
 [17, '81', '03/07/2016 - 00:54:04', '03/07/2016 - 00:58:24', '04:20'],
 [18, '80', '03/07/2016 - 00:58:24', '03/07/2016 - 01:02:44', '04:20'],
 [19, '79', '03/07/2016 - 01:02:44', '03/07/2016 - 01:07:34', '04:49'],
 [20, '78', '03/07/2016 - 01:07:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:11:54', '04:20'],
 [21, '77', '03/07/2016 - 01:11:54', '03/07/2016 - 01:16:34', '04:39'],
 [22, '77', '03/07/2016 - 01:16:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:18:54', '02:19'],
 [23, '76', '03/07/2016 - 01:18:54', '03/07/2016 - 01:20:25', '01:31'],
 [24, '75', '03/07/2016 - 01:20:25', '03/07/2016 - 01:24:34', '04:08'],
 [25, '74', '03/07/2016 - 01:24:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:28:34', '04:00'],
 [26, '73', '03/07/2016 - 01:28:34', '03/07/2016 - 01:32:44', '04:10'],
 [27, '72', '03/07/2016 - 01:32:44', '03/07/2016 - 01:37:24', '04:39'],
 [57, '100', '03/07/2016 - 02:34:31', '03/07/2016 - 08:02:49', '328:18'],
 [58, '99', '03/07/2016 - 08:02:49', '03/07/2016 - 08:05:33', '02:44'],
 [59, '99', '03/07/2016 - 08:05:33', '03/07/2016 - 08:06:43', '01:09'],
 [60, '98', '03/07/2016 - 08:06:43', '03/07/2016 - 08:09:23', '02:40'],
 [61, '97', '03/07/2016 - 08:09:23', '03/07/2016 - 08:12:03', '02:39'],
 [63, '96', '03/07/2016 - 08:16:49', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:08', '02:19'],
 [64, '95', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:08', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:58', '00:50'],
 [65, '94', '03/07/2016 - 08:19:58', '03/07/2016 - 08:24:28', '04:29'],
 [66, '93', '03/07/2016 - 08:24:28', '03/07/2016 - 08:28:28', '04:00'],
 [67, '92', '03/07/2016 - 08:28:28', '03/07/2016 - 08:32:38', '04:10'],
 [69, '91', '03/07/2016 - 08:33:18', '03/07/2016 - 08:40:13', '06:55'],
 [70, '90', '03/07/2016 - 08:40:13', '03/07/2016 - 08:45:18', '05:04'],
 [71, '90', '03/07/2016 - 08:45:18', '03/07/2016 - 08:46:18', '01:00'],
 [72, '89', '03/07/2016 - 08:46:18', '03/07/2016 - 08:50:30', '04:12'],
 [74, '88', '03/07/2016 - 09:05:23', '03/07/2016 - 09:48:53', '43:30'],
 [75, '87', '03/07/2016 - 09:48:53', '03/07/2016 - 09:50:33', '01:40'],
 [76, '86', '03/07/2016 - 09:50:33', '03/07/2016 - 09:55:03', '04:29'],
 [77, '85', '03/07/2016 - 09:55:03', '03/07/2016 - 10:00:43', '05:39'],
 [78, '84', '03/07/2016 - 10:00:43', '03/07/2016 - 10:06:47', '06:03'],
 [79, '83', '03/07/2016 - 10:06:47', '03/07/2016 - 10:12:37', '05:49'],
 [80, '82', '03/07/2016 - 10:12:37', '03/07/2016 - 10:34:35', '21:58'],
 [82, '81', '03/07/2016 - 10:36:47', '03/07/2016 - 10:57:24', '20:37'],
 [83, '81', '03/07/2016 - 10:57:24', '03/07/2016 - 10:59:04', '01:39'],
 [86, '79', '03/07/2016 - 11:01:52', '03/07/2016 - 11:03:55', '02:03'],
 [87, '79', '03/07/2016 - 11:03:55', '03/07/2016 - 11:04:55', '01:00'],
 [88, '78', '03/07/2016 - 11:04:55', '03/07/2016 - 11:07:33', '02:37'],
 [89, '77', '03/07/2016 - 11:07:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:11:23', '03:50'],
 [90, '76', '03/07/2016 - 11:11:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:16:23', '04:59'],
 [91, '75', '03/07/2016 - 11:16:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:20:23', '04:00'],
 [92, '74', '03/07/2016 - 11:20:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:24:33', '04:09'],
 [93, '73', '03/07/2016 - 11:24:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:28:33', '04:00'],
 [94, '73', '03/07/2016 - 11:28:33', '03/07/2016 - 11:29:13', '00:39'],
 [95, '73', '03/07/2016 - 11:29:13', '03/07/2016 - 11:29:53', '00:40'],
 [96, '72', '03/07/2016 - 11:29:53', '03/07/2016 - 11:32:03', '02:10'],
 [97, '71', '03/07/2016 - 11:32:03', '03/07/2016 - 11:36:23', '04:20'],
 [98, '70', '03/07/2016 - 11:36:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:40:23', '04:00'],
 [99, '69', '03/07/2016 - 11:40:23', '03/07/2016 - 11:45:03', '04:39'],
 [100, '68', '03/07/2016 - 11:45:03', '03/07/2016 - 11:58:34', '13:30'],
 [101, '67', '03/07/2016 - 11:58:34', '03/07/2016 - 12:21:10', '22:36'],
 [102, '66', '03/07/2016 - 12:21:10', '03/07/2016 - 12:24:00', '02:49']]
descarregando_tela_desligada =
[[28, '72', '03/07/2016 - 01:37:24', '03/07/2016 - 01:39:02', '01:37'],
 [62, '96', '03/07/2016 - 08:12:03', '03/07/2016 - 08:16:49', '04:45'],
 [68, '92', '03/07/2016 - 08:32:38', '03/07/2016 - 08:33:18', '00:39'],
 [73, '88', '03/07/2016 - 08:50:30', '03/07/2016 - 09:05:23', '14:52'],
 [81, '82', '03/07/2016 - 10:34:35', '03/07/2016 - 10:36:47', '02:11'],
 [84, '80', '03/07/2016 - 10:59:04', '03/07/2016 - 11:00:51', '01:46'],
 [85, '80', '03/07/2016 - 11:00:51', '03/07/2016 - 11:01:52', '01:01']]
```